# your file was import but the server returned 2 warning and /or notes.see the log pannel for details

Tags: java, mysql, sql, heidisql

I have make one data base name `nikhil` and table name `hosting`

```
nikhil.hosting(name, age,address,phone number) VALUES ('nikhil', '10', 'DELHI', '9412309536\r');
```

but when i am loading my .csv file then show the error. please help me and provide guidance . i am new in heidisql database.

Comment: can you show us the error please

Comment: can not see what this has to do with java

Comment: I am using this commands for load -LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Nikhil\\details.csv' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE `nikhil`.`test`
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Comment: and then i execute  Error show - you file uploaded. but i have different value in my .csv file ( nikhil , 10,delhi, 9412309536)

Comment: value add and show ?nikhil ,10 ,delhi ,2147483647 .  i can't Recognize thise value. because this value i have not in my csv file

Answer (score 0):

use Notepad++ to open the csv file and see the column separator fields (normally it is a comma) you can update the same on the heidisql dialog box while importing at the **Fields Terminated By** option. This is what helped me.